# Woocommerce: How to add random fee?

Tags: wordpress

### **Why i have to do this?**

I would like to add the small extra random fee to total amount in checkout page, so i can identify the customer who transfer money via bank by checking the second decimal point (random between 0.01 - 0.09).

**This is the example**

The total amount is 750. When the checkout page is load, it will add the random small fee, so the total will be 750.01 or 750.04

### **What i have done so far?**

i activate this plugin.

**"WooCommerce Extra Charges To Payment Gateway (Standard)"** by **hemsingh1**.

There is a **"calculate_totals()"** function and i have add a fix amount to test it. When i run a page, the checkout total is correct.

The problem is when i add the random number by **"rand(1,9)/100"**. It random this fee for 3 times. First random when it load the checkout page (The page is blur and can't select anything). Second random when the checkout page finish loading and the user can select the payment method. The third times in thank you page. The user will see different extra fee for 3 times. But i want the user to see the same random value.

Then i try to make a random number before loading a checkout page. 
The process is

1) I use **"add_filter"** in **"woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees"** to pick the **"random"** function

2) In **"random"** function, i random number 0.01-0.09, call function **"calculate_total"** and then use **"do_action"** to send **$random_number** into **"calculate_total"**

3) In **"calculate_total"**, i add new argument, that is **$random_number**. and inside it i add **$t1** (extra fee for this plugin) by **$random_number**.

```
class WC_PaymentGateway_Add_extra_std_Charges{
    public function __construct(){
        ....
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'random' );

}


function random() {
    $random_number = rand(1,9)/100;
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', array( $this,'calculate_totals' ), 10, 2 );
    do_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', $random_number);
}  


public function calculate_totals( $totals, $random_number ) {
    ....
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee(__($t6.$t5),**($t1 + $random_number)**,$ta1);
}
```

This approach still doesn't work. The extra fee is 0.00 all the time.
How can i solve this problem?